# Can grignard reagent contain secondary amino group?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, amines

Is there any reason why this grignard reagent wouldn't work? My best guess is that perhaps the nitrogen could act as a second nucleophilic "head", thereby not giving a good yield on the intended product. Or maybe this isn't stable enough?

[image: proposed piperidine grignard]

Comment: The variables regarding why the reagent may or may not be effective for certain processes depends a lot on what your using it for?

Comment: I'm really just wondering if there's a way it could deactivate itself, like how you shouldn't make a grignard reagent that can reach a carboxyl group on itself. Originally I intended to use it to attack benzoyl chloride. Can the grignard really deprotonate itself? It seems to me like the nitrogen's proton is too close?

Comment: I'm almost sure it can and will deprotonate and thus deactivate itself. Whether or not the nitrogen's proton is close to the Grignard site, does not matter at all.

Comment: @Ivan and the OP—Please (self-)answer this question so it wouldn't show up in the *'unanswered'* list. i.e. close the case.

Answer (score 5):

I guess it wouldn't even *exist*. Grignard's reagent is basic enough to easily take off an imine proton, so as soon as you try to make such a thing, it will turn upon itself.

Probably they have a suitable [protecting group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protecting_group) for this, but here I'm stepping outside my expertise.

Comment: Why are you calling the amine an imine?

Comment: Obviously because I mistook the secondary amine's $\ce{-NH-}$ for imine's $\ce{=NH}$. Who cares. Grignard would instantly destroy both all the same.

Comment: Just wondering, thought maybe I was missing something.