# Grignard Reagent R group

Tags: organic-chemistry, organometallic-compounds

Can the R group of a Grignard reagent (RMgX) be an alkene?

Also what groups can't R be?

Comment: Yes it can be an alkane or an alkyne too.

Comment: related http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/41235/can-grignard-reagent-contain-secondary-amino-group

Comment: R cannot have a beta leaving group because elimination occurs

Comment: There can't be any acidic groups or carbonyl groups.

Comment: No nitro groups.  They oxidize the Grignard reagent.